# Time and Date based condition in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have this code which returns Rate A or B based on time of the hour, I now want to add the date as an argument so Rates are A or B for 25/02/2023 and C or D for 26/02/2023 please:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

ts = ['2/25/2023 0:00', '2/25/2023 0:10', '2/25/2023 0:35', '2/25/2023 0:59', '2/25/2023 1:04', '2/26/2023 0:05', '2/26/2023 0:38', '2/26/2023 1:07', 
        '2/26/2023 10:08', '2/26/2023 10:59']

temp = ['0', '21', '20', '30', '40', '50', '6', '7', '8', '9']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ts, temp)),
                  columns = ['ts', 'temp'])
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
df1 = df.set_index('ts')


def get_rate(row):
    if row.minute < 30:
        return 'A'
    else:
        return 'B'

df1['Rate'] = df1.index.map(get_rate)
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can define a dictionary `rates`, where keys are dates and values are 2-item lists (first value for minute < 30, second for >= 30):

```py
import datetime

def get_rate(row, rates):
    d = rates.get(row.date())
    if not d:
        return np.nan

    return d[row.minute >= 30]


rates = {
    datetime.date(day=25, month=2, year=2023): ["A", "B"],
    datetime.date(day=26, month=2, year=2023): ["C", "D"],
}

df1["Rate"] = df1.index.map(lambda v: get_rate(v, rates=rates))
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
                    temp Rate
ts                           
2023-02-25 00:00:00    0    A
2023-02-25 00:10:00   21    A
2023-02-25 00:35:00   20    B
2023-02-25 00:59:00   30    B
2023-02-25 01:04:00   40    A
2023-02-26 00:05:00   50    C
2023-02-26 00:38:00    6    D
2023-02-26 01:07:00    7    C
2023-02-26 10:08:00    8    C
2023-02-26 10:59:00    9    D
```

---

But you can do this more easily:

```py
df1.loc["25/02/2023", "Rate"] = np.where(
    df1.loc["25/02/2023"].index.minute < 30, "A", "B"
)

df1.loc["26/02/2023", "Rate"] = np.where(
    df1.loc["26/02/2023"].index.minute < 30, "C", "D"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to change 'A' into 'C' and 'B' into 'D' for the 26th day, you can adjust the `get_rate` function like this:

```
def get_rate(row):
    rate = ''
    if row.minute < 30:
        rate = 'A'
    else:
        rate = 'B'
    if row.day == 26:
        rate = chr(ord(rate) + 2)
    return rate
```

---

```
                    temp Rate
ts
2023-02-25 00:00:00    0    A
2023-02-25 00:10:00   21    A
2023-02-25 00:35:00   20    B
2023-02-25 00:59:00   30    B
2023-02-25 01:04:00   40    A
2023-02-26 00:05:00   50    C
2023-02-26 00:38:00    6    D
2023-02-26 01:07:00    7    C
2023-02-26 10:08:00    8    C
2023-02-26 10:59:00    9    D
```